# d3.js Changing the opacity of nodes and it's outgoing and incoming links based on a filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, radio-button, graph-visualization

I have a fully working force directed graph.

I am trying to add radio buttons and clicking on them should dynamically change the opacity of nodes , based on a condition.

**HTML**

```
    <style>
  .links line {
    stroke: #999;
    stroke-opacity: 0.6;
  }

  .nodes circle {
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }

  .nodes circle {
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }

  div.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    max-width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-width: 1px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    pointer-events: none;
  }

</style>
<svg id="Network_graph" width="400" height="350"></svg>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="legend">
  <h3>Filter</h3>
  <div class="input-group" id="filters">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="filter" value="All" checked="checked"> All</label>
    <br />
    <label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="filter" value="Agent"> Agent</label>
      <br />
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="filter" value="Customer"> Customer</label>
      <br />
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="filter" value="Phone"> Phone</label>
      <br />
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="filter" value="ID_Card"> ID_Card </label>

  </div>
</div>





</button>
```

My JSON data is of the below format:

**JSON**

```
var IDData = JSON.stringify([
  ["node/105173", "node/38180995", "Agent", "Customer", "1379644.0", 1, 264, "1374903"],
  ["node/1061", "node/21373542", "Agent", "Customer", "530848.0", 1, 3000, "529502"],
  ["node/10750", "node/59648369", "Agent", "Customer", "1454228.0", 1, 120, "1454118"],
  ["node/10750", "node/78569210", "Agent", "Customer", "1425251.0", 1, 234, "1421416"],
  ["node/10750", "node/96726118", "Agent", "Customer", "1376239.0", 1, 434, "1376152"],
  ["node/10946829", "node/11190", "Customer", "Agent", "1409620.0", 20, 3380, "1406665"],
  ["node/10946829", "node/57774036", "Customer", "Customer", "1460029.0", 3, 960, "1459731"],
  ["node/109947", "node/97911872", "Agent", "Customer", "1323025.0", 1, 600, "1315582"],..])
```

Using this function , I convert this JSON data in a suitable format to render the graphs,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    console.log(IDData);
    var galData = JSON.parse(IDData);
    var startnodes = [];
    var endnodes = [];
    var startnodetype = [];
    var endnodetype = [];
    var PayTime = [];
    var TXN_COUNT = [];
    var Total_Amt = [];
    var SendTime = [];
    galData.map(function(e, i) {
        startnodes.push(e[0]);
        endnodes.push(e[1]);
        startnodetype.push(e[2]);
        endnodetype.push(e[3]);
        PayTime.push(e[4]);
        TXN_COUNT.push(e[5]);
        Total_Amt.push(e[6]);
        SendTime.push(e[7]);
    });
    var final_data = createNodes(startnodes, endnodes, startnodetype, endnodetype, depth, PayTime, TXN_COUNT, Total_Amt, SendTime);
    makeGraph("#Network_graph", final_data);

});
```

Working [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vishy1988/7tkp2g8w/5/) is here.It is inspired from this example of [d3.js library](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045).

So , my graph has 4 types of Nodes ; Agent,Customer,Phone,ID_Card. These are represented by

```
  d.type
```

So , now I have written this below piece of code; that should filter the graph based on the radio button being selected, So , for instance selection on radio button with value "Agent" should reduce the opacity of other nodes and links , except those links that are outgoing and incoming from all "Agent" nodes.

```
d3.selectAll("input[name=filter]").on("change", function(d){


      var value = this.value;

      node.style("opacity", 1);
      link.style("opacity", 1);


      if (value !== "all"){
        value = +this.value;
        node.filter(function(d){
          return d.type != value;
        })
        .style("opacity", "0.5");

        link.filter(function(d){
          return d.source.type != value ||
                 d.target.type != value;
        })
        .style("opacity", "0.5");
      }



    });
```

Seems like there is something missing still and running this is not changing the opacity. I am very new to javascrpt and d3.js and lack expertise. So , looking for some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems here.

**Problem 1: Scope**

Inside your "change" function, you're making reference to `node` and `link`. But both `node` and `link` exist only inside `makeGraph` function.

The solution is moving all that event handler to inside `makeGraph` function.

**Problem 2: Type conversion**

When you do this:

```
value = +this.value;
```

You're trying to convert a string which has no numbers to a number. So:

```
console.log(+this.value);//returns NaN
```

And you're not doing anything with NaN.

Solution: keep the strings.

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u9y4m32k/

Comment: The +this.value was a stupid typo. Thanks for the other part though. Much appreciated...:).